# How to format two strings delimited with whitespace in variable to be seen as one string?

Tags: variables, ksh

I have one variable, which contents are like:

```
echo $var1
"string1 string2" "string3 string4" "string5 string6"
```

I would like for "string1 string2" and etc, to be seen as one string, currently if I print first field with awk I get '"word1'as first field, second field is 'word2"' and so on.

When I use this variable in a for loop it doesn't work because for loop doesn't see strings under quotation marks as one string.

For example I tried:

```
for i in "${var1[@]}";do command to run program with arguments "$i";done
```

- this doesn't work cause program is runned with '"string1 argument, while it should be run with '"string1 string2" argument.

Furthermore, while I create another variable $var2 like:

```
var2=("string1 string2" "string3 string4")
```

and run it within above for loop, it works.

My question is, is there a way to format $var1 to look like $var2 in above examples, in order for it to work? Thank you.

Note: $var1 is a result of a program which fetches names of services.

Comment: please review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); at a minimum we're looking for the code you've tried, the (wrong) output you're currently generating, and the (good) expected output you'd like to generate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want the resulting strings with quotes, use

```
echo "$var1" | grep -Eo '"[^"]*"' | while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo "l=$line"
done
```

Result:

```
l="string1 string2"
l="string3 string4"
l="string5 string6"
```

Without quotes:

```
echo "$var1" | grep -Eo '"[^"]*"' | while IFS='"' read -r x line x ; do
   echo "l=$line"
done
```

Result:

```
l=string1 string2
l=string3 string4
l=string5 string6
```

Comment: thank you, this actually worked. One question though, what -o option does in grep?
I'm using AIX with ksh and bash 4.2 so -o option doesn't work

Comment: The `-o` option doesn't return the whole line of a match, but only the matched string. I used itto split the line into different lines with each only one quoted string. I do not know how you managed to get it working without `grep -Eo`, perhaps you did something like `$ echo '"1 1" "2 2" "3 3"' | sed -r 's/"[^"]*"/&\n/g' | while IFS='"' read -r x line x; do test -n "$line" && echo "l=$line"; done` (or `\n` replaced with a real newline when your `sed` doesn't support `\n`).

Comment: I used your command only without -o option, everything else stayed put. 
`echo "$var1" | grep -E '"[^"]*"' | while IFS='"' read -r x line x ;do echo "Deleted lines: $line\n";done`